# Remove the text before second comma ('',") String replace pattern

Tags: regex, string, scala, str-replace

how can we remove the text before the line that start's with second comma(line 5 in the example),how can i do that using regex?
example :

```
,
abc,xyz,ggg,nrmr
cde,jjj,kkkk,iiii,tem,posting
234,mm/dd/yy
,
454654,output2,sample
45646,output1,non-sample
16546,225.02
ABC,2.98
```

expected :

```
454654,output2,sample
45646,output1,non-sample
16546,225.02
ABC,2.98
```

Comment: Try http://ideone.com/f9pVW2

Comment: thanks,
how can we remove the text before the line 5 in the above example?

Comment: Try http://ideone.com/BaoC8H

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly, if possible can you explain the 
(?sm)^(.*?^,$) regex pattern?

Comment: Actually, there is a mistake. You need `"(?sm)\\A(.*?^,$){2}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
val s = """,
abc,xyz,ggg,nrmr
cde,jjj,kkkk,iiii,tem,posting
234,mm/dd/yy
,
454654,output2,sample
45646,output1,non-sample
16546,225.02
ABC,2.98"""
val res = s.replaceFirst("(?sm)\\A(.*?^,$){2}", "").trim()
println(res)
// => 
//   454654,output2,sample
//   45646,output1,non-sample
//   16546,225.02
//   ABC,2.98
```

See the [Scala demo](http://ideone.com/7YEx0s).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?sm)` - `s` enables `.` to match any char in the string including newlines, and `m` makes `^` and `$` match start/end of line respectively
- `\\A` - the start of string
- `(.*?^,$){2}` - 2 occurrences of:

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the leftmost
  - `^,$` - line that only contains `,`.